# Right column of 3 column layout missing after upload

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I have a local site running on XAMPP that I am happy with.
I've uploaded the site to our remote server, nearly everything is okay (couple of URL's needed changing) apart from the right column of the 3 column layout is missing.
Magento Version 1.9.2.4

Please see images below of the issue.
**Local Version:**
[image: Local Version]
**Remote Version:**
[image: Remote Version]